# Is there a way to instruct LaTeX compilation to recreate PDFs from EPS graphics? (pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, eps

When I compile a LaTeX document containing EPS graphics to PDF, all EPS graphics are compiled to PDFs first. This is great! But if I replace the EPS graphics, but do not delete the PDF files created from those, the next time I compile the LaTeX document, the EPS graphics will (sensibly) not be compiled to PDF files again (so I get the old ones in my PDF output).

Can I tell LaTeX (`pdflatex`) to recompile the eps files if I need to?

Comment: no, not by default. It just does a file exists check. You could redefine things to do a check if the eps is newer, but there is no interface to that, you would have to redefine the internal macros.